# XML file is couldn't located Android

Tags: android

I'm new to Android and developing.i made two package's, in one package my xml file doesn't identified. please find below the code I used.

```
Error:test cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

**com.tabs.compareNow.java**

```
package com.tabs;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.R;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class compareNow extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);// **test.xml not identified** 

    }

}
```

**res/layout.test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >    
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the below import

```
import android.R;
```

You need to import R from your package

```
import com.tabs.R;
```

considering `com.tabs` in your package name

Make sure you have the xml under `res/layout/test.xml`

Also check if you have any errors in your resource files. If so your `R.java` will not be generated. So in that case you need to fix the errors and then clean and build the project.

Also follow java naming conventions.

Although not wrong Change `compareNow` to `CompareNow`

Answer (score 1):

remove it `import android.R;`

and import with `import packagename.R;`

Answer (score 0):

Change name to test.xml not layout.test.xml and put it in res/layout folder

Answer (score 0):

```
try it with these::--> remove  import android.R;  
import com.tabs.R;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove it

```
import android.R;
```

Becoz this is Referencing the Android Resources into the Project.
So you cannot find your Layout view id

Add

```
import com.tabs.R;
```

Clean Your Project that's it